# Pass anything in URL Django and return page

Tags: python, django

I want that if I pass anything in URL, Django will accept that

```
path('user/username/update/<str:id>/', views.update_activities,
     name='update_activity_on_selected_user'),
```

I want that everything that will passed on line **username**, it will return that function of updating.

path('user/**username**/update/str:id/', views.update_activities,
name='update_activity_on_selected_user'),

Answer (score 0):

You can use slug instead of str, slug matches any slug string consisting of ASCII letters or numbers, plus the hyphen and underscore characters. For example.

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/2003/', views.special_case_2003),
    path('articles/<int:year>/', views.year_archive),
    path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/', views.month_archive),
    path('articles/<int:year>/<int:month>/<slug:slug>/', views.article_detail),
]
```

Here is the example doc link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#example